# What can lead invaders to adopt the culture of the invaded?

Tags: warfare, culture, invasion, assimilation

In my world I need people of culture A to invade the lands inhabited by people of culture B. The invasion is successful and A conquers the territory. However, the A people adopt the B culture to a large extent, rather than imposing their own culture on B, causing them to diverge from the A people who stayed in their homeland.

I know that real history has examples of invaders adopting the culture of the invaded, but in general, what are the factors you expect to see for this to take place?

For context, the B people live in an island about the size of Madagascar and both A and B are comparable technology-wise (roughly tribal/pre-feudal), so it's not like barbarians invading Rome.

Comment: The Romans often appointed local leaders to maintain order in the conquered region. This helped limit insurgencies because the leader seemed more legitimate than a foreigner. We can very well imagine that this kind of cultural mix and the presence of locals in power ended up over time by privileging the cultures of the conquered rather than the conquerors.

Comment: @Alex: The Roman empire was a *very*, *extremely* decentralized state. Compared to the Roman empire, the USA is positively Napoleonical. Basically each and every city in the empire governed itself, as it had always done. The Romans very seldom "appointed" people to govern cities; they left it to the people of those cities to do it the way they had always done it. "Governors" of provinces had limited attributions, mostly having to do with taxes and the army; they did not "govern" in the modern sense.

Comment: Perhaps the invaders thought the invaded's culture/societal norms were objectively better. Doesn't preclude the need of the invaders to invade the to-be-invaded.

Comment: Ask folks at Coachella, they seem like they would know

Comment: @AlexP Like a nation-state mafia wanting protection money and not much else.

Comment: @DKNguyen: Actually the taxes to the Empire were quite low, and were mostly spent on the army and on financing the kind of public works individual cities could not, for example the famous roads. What the empire provided was peace, a functional legal and judicial system, and most importantly a large common market. That's about it. Modern states do so very much more, and as a consequence need to extract twenty times more tax.

Comment: "Romans" is the right answer, just at the wrong end of the time scale: specifically, notice how the invading Franks took on the language, religion, culture and lifestyle of the native Romans. Sure they bequeathed a few words to the nascent French language, but the conquerors pretty much went native and disappeared into the foreground.

Comment: Interesting segway. Apparently the hykos invasion of old northern egypt wasn't so much an "invasion" but a period of immigration and then those 5th/6th gen immigrants coming into political power. Later political slander then turned it into an "invasion" as recorded in history.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is usually determined by (1) numbers, (2) unequal levels of civilization and (3) particular situations in each case.

- If the conquerors are much fewer than the conquered, or
- if the conquerors are barbarians and the conquered are much more advanced in civilization and technology, or
- if the conquerors didn't bring women with them,

then it almost certain that the conquering culture will dissolve into the conquered culture.

Examples:

- The conquerors are much fewer than the conquered: the French-speaking Normans in England. It will take a few generations, but eventually if the numerical difference is too large, the conquering culture will eventually wither and die.
- The conquerors are much fewer than the conquered, *and* they didn't bring women with them: the Norsemen (= Vikings) in Normandy and the Varangians (= Vikings) in Kievan Russia. (The Vikings were experts at conquering lands and then promptly losing their culture and going native. Those are not the only examples.)

  (Women are essential because they are the driving force in preserving the culture over generations. There is a reason why we say mother tongue and not father tongue. Not bringing women practically guarantees the loss of the conquering culture in two or three generations.)
- The conquerors are barbarians and the conquered are much more advanced in civilization and technology: the Germanic tribes in the Western Roman Empire, the Mongols in China and India, the Arabs in Persia.

  Barbarians are great warriors, but poor administrators. Wise barbarians will rely on local administrators, and this will inevitably lead to the merger of the conquering culture in the local culture, albeit usually leaving clear influences. For example, the Persians adopted the religion of the conquering Arabs, while preserving their distinct Persian language and culture.

<sup>The question asks about "invaders". I have answered about "conquerors", because invasions do not necessarily have to be successful; see the British, the Russians and the Americans in Afghanistan, for an example recurring every century or so.</sup>

Comment: Why not add a section about invaders. If an invasion fails, the invaders can scatter and some join society there, adapting to the culture.

Comment: @Trioxidane: I would have to invent my own scenario of the invasion, the failure mode, the local culture... It is much more complicated, and the question doesn't provide any starting point. The failed invaders may leave, they may be killed, they may be enslaved, they may be expelled forcefully... It's complicated.

Comment: true. I just thought that it might be an extra answer how invaders *could* adopt the culture. Feel free to add or omit.

Comment: I really doubt that you can make a case that the Norman culture in England withered and died, rather than forming a hybrid culture.  For instance, Google suggest that a majority of English words are derived from French or Latin roots.

Comment: @jamesqf -- It's also true that middle class Englishmen during the 12th & 13th centuries actively sought to learn French. It's also true that it took a long time to entirely switch over to English: [400 or 500 years](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/26736/who-was-the-last-english-king-whose-first-language-was-french) for the nobility to make the switch; and a further century or two for the lawyers to abandon French, except for a very few terms like "oyez", "force majeur", and "la reyne le veult"

Comment: @jamesqf: The French influence on the English language was indeed massive, yet English remained a Germanic language. (And the Romance languages themselves show large Germanic, or Arabic, or Slavic influences, depending on their individual histories. All, or at least *most*, cultures are in a way "hybrids". Pure cultures are rare, if they exist at all. But it is quite obvious that the English and French cultures are *very* distinct; I could even argue that the English culture is sufficiently distinct to be opposable to the "continental" European cultures as a group.

Comment: @elemtilas: But my point is that it wasn't a switch over, it was the development of a hybrid language, Middle English, then modern English.  As for whether English is Germanic or not, from my own experience it's a heck of a lot easier to learn French than German.  And FWIW modern English & French cultures are much more like each other than their Norman & English ancestors.

Comment: @jamesqf -- Linguistically, English is totally Germanic. We have a lot of French words is ll. Culture may be hybridised.

Comment: @elemtilas: Yes, hybridized.  Exactly the point I was trying to make about the Normans in England.  As for whether English is a Germanic language, perhaps to a linguist it is.  To someone trying to learn the language, or trying to navigate without actually knowing the language, French is much closer to English than German, at least in my experience.  Again, the result of that hybridization.

Comment: @jamesqf -- But even then, English culture (and language) were already hybridised pre-invasion: Anglo-Saxon had long been hybridised with Viking culture (Danelaw anyone?) and the language even borrowed a couple pronouns from Norse (grammatical words are usually very resistant to borrowing) as well as some other lexical items. As far as learning modern English, sure, knowing French gives a leg up as far as vocabulary acquisition is concerned. As far as grammar goes, neither French (which is the most innovative of the Romance languages) nor German will be of much help.

Answer (score 3):

Some combination of:

1. It makes the conquered more tractable
2. The conquerors can only really rule with the tools of the conquered.  (Mongol governance was not sufficient to govern and collect taxes from China.)
3. It's the only practical way to live in that land.  (The conquered land lacks grazing for horses; your horse-dependent culture does not work.)
4. It is more pleasant than their own.  Expect this to be denounced by the conquerors, but insisting that their officials walk or ride horses when they could travel by sedan chair is not going to be popular with the officials.

Answer (score 2):

#### Keep the wheels turning.

So, this is a great day. Your nomadic horde has finally conquered that rich agricultural country. YOUR word is now THEIR law.

First day of business, two local villagers ask you to solve their dispute (you are now the law, after all). They explain to you the long history of ownership of the land of dispute.

This is mind numbling to you. Your people has never cultivated the land, so they have never worried about "owning" it. They do not have rules to decide who owns the land. You do not know the pros or cons of each decission.

So you pick one of the former ruler's advisors out of jail (preferibly one who still has a tongue in himself) so he can inform you of the usual way of solving this issue. That way, both parties have a ruling and they can go back to their fields and continue produce food for the court.

Well, that was a good day at work. Now, where are the concubines? This damn palace is SO great.

In order to reap the profits of your victory, the society conquered needs to keep working. Which means management. But your nomadic lifestyle provides no guidance to do so, so you keep the previous administration in place.

With time:

- Your nomadic tribe becomes settled as lords, so the nomadic traditions are no longer useful.
- You realize that you need to keep an eye to maximize the profits of using the old system. Learn how it works, and you may tweak a law there or here so you get to reward an ally, or to get more revenue.